# Webpack maximum chunk size

Tags: webpack

My current configuration is 1 bundle.js file with the main stuff the application needs (angular etc..) and all the others are lazy loaded via require.ensure in the application code.

After minify the bundle.js is above 100KB with just the basics for the application.
Is it possible to tell webpack to split the main bundle to max 20KB or so chunks so the browser can download them concurrently?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't come across a good way to split chunks based on the bundle result itself.  You can set a min size for output chunks so that they are merged when there aren't many bytes in your chunk.

```
    // This plugin prevents Webpack from creating chunks
    // that would be too small to be worth loading separately
    new webpack.optimize.MinChunkSizePlugin({
        minChunkSize: 51200, // ~50kb
    }),
```

But, I know that's not what you're looking for. Unfortunately, it looks like nobody has written anything like that yet.  Sounds like an interesting [plugin to write](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/how-to-write-a-plugin)!

Also, Take a look at this blog, which walks through some of the splitting basics.
http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with "AggressiveSplittingPlugin". You can find it here:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/http2-aggressive-splitting

Please note that this plugin is available only if you use webpack 2.

Comment: If you are using webpack 1, you can use some other plugins, that split your chunks by path - e.g. all  the files from chunk 1 that are from "lib" directory will be in a new chunk. Here are 2 plugins that can do it for you: "https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-split-chunks and "https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-split-by-path

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.